# How to remap mouse button to keyboard button

Tags: android, keymapping

I have a remote control with gyroscope. It has these buttons:

```
            home
settings    OK      back
            info

            zoom-in
            zoom-out
```

I need to test GUI without gyro, so I want to transform them into

```
        up
left    enter   right
        down

        home
        back
```

I had no problems with assigning left, up, down, home and back as they all had keyboard codes.
For example, I've replaced `key 59    SETTINGS` with `key 59    DPAD_LEFT` in Generic.kl (I'll create device-specific keylayout later)

However, original `back` button have code 273 (0x111). There were no such key in Generic.kl.

Adding `key 0x111 DPAD_RIGHT` or `key 273   DPAD_RIGHT` didn't work.
Just in case, here is `getevent` output for this key press:

```
/dev/input/event4: 0004 0004 00090002
/dev/input/event4: 0001 0111 00000001
/dev/input/event4: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event4: 0004 0004 00090002
/dev/input/event4: 0001 0111 00000000
/dev/input/event4: 0000 0000 00000000
```

So, how do I remap this key ?